# How to force JSON serialization to include type information for a polymorphic System.Enum member?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, enums, json.net

I am using JSON serialization and deserialization for serialize/deserialize the storage class of my big application. 
some where in my application, I need to hold the enums of different enumsType in an Enum or sum times i will need to hold the different classes inherited from a parent class to a variable of type of parent class. please look at the below code which demonstrate an example for an enum. in these situation, the serialization gets error especially for enums and cannot find the enum because the type of variable in Enum. for example in the below sample code the inputEnum is of type Enum and can get enums of Enum1 and Enum2. but in deserialization the Json brings error that cannot convert int64 to type of Enum.
Now I need the JSON to hold the original type of the variables to deserialize them. for example in `inputenum=Enum1.hi`, the type to be hold as Enum1 instead of Enum that is occurring now.
Please give your solutions.

```
    public enum Enum1
    {
        hi=0,
        hello
    }
    public enum Enum2
    {
        by = 0,
        goodbye
    }
    public class TUnitClass
    {
        public string Id { set; get; }
        public string Name { set; get; }
        public Enum inputenum { set; get; }
        public string Comment { set; get; }
        public string displayingString { set; get; }


    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<TUnitClass> cls1=new List<TUnitClass>()
        {
            new TUnitClass() {inputenum = Enum2.goodbye},
            new TUnitClass() {inputenum = Enum2.by},
            new TUnitClass() {inputenum = Enum1.hello},
            new TUnitClass() {inputenum = Enum1.hi},
            new TUnitClass() {inputenum = Enum2.goodbye},
        };
        string strSerialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cls1);
        List<TUnitClass> cls2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TUnitClass>>(strSerialized,new JsonSerializerSettings() {Error = ErrorOnDeserialization});
    }
    private void ErrorOnDeserialization(object sender, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ErrorEventArgs e)
    {



    }
```

**Update**

I have attempted to implement the solution from [Deserialize specific enum into system.enum in Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31351262/3744182).  Type information is correctly written to the JSON file during serialization, however during deserialization an exception is thrown:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException occurred
  Message="Type specified in JSON 'MTC.Utility.UnitConvertor.TypeWrapper`1[[MTC.Utility.UnitConvertor.EAcceleration, MTC.Utility.UnitConvertor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], MTC.Utility.UnitConvertor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not compatible with 'System.Enum, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Path 'listOfUnitSystems[0].UnitsList[0].Unit.$type', line 17, position 269."
  Source="Newtonsoft.Json"
  StackTrace:
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ResolveTypeName(JsonReader reader, Type& objectType, JsonContract& contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, String qualifiedTypeName) in C:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Working-Signed\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 814
  InnerException:
```

Here is the updated code:

```
public abstract class TypeWrapper
{
    protected TypeWrapper() { }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public abstract object ObjectValue { get; }

    public static TypeWrapper CreateWrapper<T>(T value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return new TypeWrapper<T>();
        var type = value.GetType();
        if (type == typeof(T))
            return new TypeWrapper<T>(value);
        // Return actual type of subclass
        return (TypeWrapper)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TypeWrapper<>).MakeGenericType(type), value);
    }
}

public sealed class TypeWrapper<T> : TypeWrapper
{
    public TypeWrapper() : base() { }

    public TypeWrapper(T value)
        : base()
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public override object ObjectValue { get { return Value; } }

    public T Value { get; set; }
}

public class TUnitClass
{
    public string Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public EQuantities Quantity { set; get; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public System.Enum Unit { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Unit", TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All)]
    TypeWrapper UnitValue
    {
        get
        {
            return Unit == null ? null : TypeWrapper.CreateWrapper(Unit);
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null || value.ObjectValue == null)
                Unit = null;
            else
                Unit = (Enum)value.ObjectValue;
        }
    }
    public string Comment { set; get; }
    public string displayingString { set; get; }
    public TUnitClass(string id, EQuantities quantity,Enum unit, string comment)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = quantity.ToString();
        Quantity = quantity;
        Unit = unit;
        Comment = comment;

        FieldInfo fi = unit.GetType().GetField(unit.ToString());
        DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
        displayingString= attributes[0].Description;
    }
}
```

**Update 2**

Finally, If I have an `Enum[]` property instead of `Enum`, how can I behave with this problem?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Deserialize specific enum into system.enum in Json.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31351262/3744182).

Comment: i have used the method in that but i have a problem in deserialization which brings null however the serialized string is not null.!also does not bring any error on deserialization

Comment: OK, then can you [edit] your question to show the attempt that did not work, or alternatively add a https://dotnetfiddle.net/ demonstrating the problem with the linked solution?

Comment: You start from the wrong point. Do not serialize anything with Json.Net and be surprised by the outcome to design your data contract with the rest of the world. Start with a contract design and how you will share the data. After that implement this contract in code

Comment: hi Sir Rufo, can you provide a link to explain your solution?. thank you

Comment: This is not a concrete solution, just a way of thinking

Comment: Have a look at my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37659536/delphi-create-json/37674405#37674405 although it is not c# related it describes the concept which is not related to any programming language

Comment: The answer from [question 31351262](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31353162/3744182) seems to work.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/KGlIxh

Comment: @dbc Of course "it works" within **that** special application, but most the time I use json to communicate with applications I do not know. Why should I choose such a contract that will expose the internally used type from my application? I choose contracts that are easy to implement for any application written in any programming language.

Comment: i have used the method mentioned by dbc but it seems that it has the problem with the enums in other assemblies rather than main assembly.

Comment: @all - does using `TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full` in `JsonSerializerSettings` resolve the issue?

Comment: @all - I was not able to reproduce the problem with the [question 31351262 answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31353162/3744182) even when the Enum was in a different project.  In that case Json.NET's  [serialization binder](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DefaultSerializationBinder.cs) loaded the enum's assembly as required.  If an exception was thrown can you [edit] your question to include full `ToString()` output of the exception including message, traceback and inner exception?

Comment: @dbc - hi and thank you. i have re-produced my problem in a solution with two projects. how can i share it with you?

Comment: @all - You could upload your files to http://pastebin.com/.  See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15821/stack-overflow-etiquette-for-sharing-files-and-resources or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47689/how-can-i-attach-a-file-to-a-stack-overflow-post

Comment: @dbc - can i send the project privately(because it is owned by my comany)?

Comment: @all - no, I don't want to look at anything that may be confidential.  Also note the following from the bottom of the page: *user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required.*  Can you boil it down to a [mcve] solution with two projects containing just the necessary types that can be shared under the stackoverflow license?

Comment: @dbc - i can do that. the project in in elow adress. please see the mainwindow.xaml.cs in wpfapplication1. http://s4.picofile.com/file/8284422792/question.rar.html

Comment: This is a bit out of topic, but I think it's ugly to have a class named TUnitClass, or any other TSomething.

Comment: @AFract - i am agree with you but it is one of my company regulations!!!

Comment: @all Is it because the T means something in this specific case or do they just force you to prefix every class with a T ? Wonderful :D

Comment: @AFract - No. they force to do that in order to the distinguish between our  classes and the original .net classes or other developer classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the solution from [question 31351262](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31353162/3744182) does not work is that your type `TUnitClass` does not have a default constructor.  Instead, it has a single parameterized constructor.  In cases like this, Json.NET will invoke that constructor, matching JSON objects to constructor arguments by name, modulo case.  (For details, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41555998/3744182).)  And unfortunately your constructor takes an abstract `System.Enum` as its `unit` argument:

```
public TUnitClass(string id, EQuantities quantity, Enum unit, string comment)
{
}
```

Json.NET will deserialize the surrogate `TypeWrapper<TEnum>` correctly but then try to cast it to a `System.Enum` in order to call the constructor, and fail, throwing the exception you are seeing.

The solution is to add a constructor that accepts a surrogate `TypeWrapper unit` value, and mark that constructor with [`[JsonConstructor]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConstructorAttribute.htm).  It can be private as long as it is marked with `[JsonConstructor]`.  The following should work:

```
public class TUnitClass
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    TUnitClass(string id, EQuantities quantity, TypeWrapper<Enum> unit, string comment)
        : this(id, quantity, unit.Value(), comment)
    {
    }

    public TUnitClass(string id, EQuantities quantity, Enum unit, string comment)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = quantity.ToString();
        Quantity = quantity;
        Unit = unit;
        Comment = comment;

        FieldInfo fi = unit.GetType().GetField(unit.ToString());
        DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
        displayingString = attributes[0].Description;
    }

    public string Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public EQuantities Quantity { set; get; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public System.Enum Unit { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Unit", TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All)]
    TypeWrapper<Enum> UnitSurrogate
    {
        get
        {
            return Unit == null ? null : TypeWrapper<Enum>.CreateWrapper(Unit);
        }
        set
        {
            Unit = value.Value();
        }
    }

    public string Comment { set; get; }
    public string displayingString { set; get; }

    public TUnitClass Copy()
    {
        TUnitClass copiedUnitClass=new TUnitClass(Id,Quantity,Unit,Comment);
        return copiedUnitClass;
    }
}

public abstract class TypeWrapper<TBase>
{
    protected TypeWrapper() { }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public abstract TBase BaseValue { get; }

    public static TypeWrapper<TBase> CreateWrapper<TDerived>(TDerived value) where TDerived : TBase
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;
        var type = value.GetType();
        if (type == typeof(TDerived))
            return new TypeWrapper<TDerived, TBase>(value);
        // Return actual type of subclass
        return (TypeWrapper<TBase>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TypeWrapper<,>).MakeGenericType(type, typeof(TBase)), value);
    }
}

public static class TypeWrapperExtensions
{
    public static TBase Value<TBase>(this TypeWrapper<TBase> wrapper)
    {
        if (wrapper == null || wrapper.BaseValue == null)
            return default(TBase);
        return wrapper.BaseValue;
    }
}

public sealed class TypeWrapper<TDerived, TBase> : TypeWrapper<TBase> where TDerived : TBase
{
    public TypeWrapper() : base() { }

    public TypeWrapper(TDerived value)
        : base()
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public override TBase BaseValue { get { return Value; } }

    public TDerived Value { get; set; }
}
```

`TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full` should no longer be necessary.

Note I modified the linked answer to add type safety to ensure the serialized type is in fact a `System.Enum`, which should increase security by preventing unexpected types during deserialization.  See [TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39565954/3744182) for a general discussion of `TypeNameHandling` security.

**Update**

*If I have a `Enum[]` instead of `Enum,` how can I behave with this problem?*

You would need to use a surrogate array of `TypeWrapper<Enum>` objects, like so:

```
public class TUnitArrayClass
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    TUnitArrayClass(TypeWrapper<Enum>[] units)
        : this(units == null ? null : units.Select(s => s.Value()).ToArray())
    {
    }

    public TUnitArrayClass(IEnumerable<System.Enum> units)
    {
        this.Units = (units ?? Enumerable.Empty<System.Enum>()).ToArray();
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public System.Enum[] Units { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Unit", TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All)]
    TypeWrapper<Enum> [] UnitsSurrogate
    {
        get
        {
            return Units == null ? null : Units.Select(u => TypeWrapper<Enum>.CreateWrapper(u)).ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                Units = null;
            else
                Units = value.Select(s => s.Value()).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think the title is not clear. please edit it as what you know.

Comment: thanks alot. i'm very shameful because of this huge disturbance. one another question. if i have a Enum[] instead of Enum, how can i behave with this problem? i used this code but it does not solve the problem. when i survayed the serialized string i found that the type wrapper has distinguished the type as Enum[]!

Comment: [JsonIgnore]
            public Enum[] Units { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("Units", TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All)]
            private TypeWrapper UnitsValue
            {
                get
                {
                    return Units == null ? null : TypeWrapper.CreateWrapper(Units);
                }
                set { Units = value.Value<Enum[]>(); }
            }

Comment: You would need to add a surrogate `TypeWrapper<Enum> [] UnitValues` that returns an array of typewrapper objects.

Comment: you mean the code must be as below?(it has errors!)private TypeWrapper<Enum>[] UnitsValue
            {
                get
                {
                    return Units == null ? null : TypeWrapper<Enum>[].CreateWrapper(Units);
                }
                set { Units = value.Value(); }
            }

Comment: @all - answer updated.  If you need additional help, please ask another question, as the preferred format for questions on stackoverflow is [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post).

Comment: i don't know how to thank you. it works very very well. thank you again.